# How to resolve Java class path not found?

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, jax-ws

I am new to Java Socket programming. I have three Java projects: a JAX-WS web service, normal java application(client) and a sock project. The web service and the client works fine, the problem occurs with the socket server. I can not consume it from the client. Every time I make an attempt , it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Document
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at SocketClient.executeOperation(SocketClient.java:69)
    at SocketClient.processOperation(SocketClient.java:38)
    at SocketClient.main(SocketClient.java:97)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: can you post you class with main method ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. This problem has been solved by moving the classes into one package. But I don't know how did it solve it.